# Text in search gets truncated if it contains Javascript function names

Tags: javascript

For example, if I type *onclick* in the search text field, the text gets cleared on submit and the results are not filtered. If I type *buttontext*, this gets truncated to *butt* (*ontext* is removed) and the results are filtered on *butt*. Any ideas on what's happening? Here's the code for the submit button:

```
<a id="SearchButton" class="button" href="#" onClick="document.forms[0].submitAction.value='search';document.forms[0].submit()">Search</a>
```

Comment: do you have any onSubmit method?

Comment: Is it possible that wherever you are posting this form to is the culprit?

Comment: I've checked that code and there doesn't seem to be anything that could change the value. And since it's just the javascript names that are being removed I assumed it's happening on the page.

Comment: Well.. share more code perhaps? The code you have written here is pretty harmless. What other javascript is there on the page. That has got to be it. Feels like someone was tryign to split on keyword "on" perhaps to do an `eval()` somewhere.